# How to install an INF file with InstallShield LE?

Tags: inf, installshield-le

We have an application for which we're using InstallShield LE (the one that comes with Visual Studio 2010) to manage the installation of the application.

As part of the installation, I need to install an INF file so the app can communicate with the modem

How can I get InstallShield LE to do this? Is this possible? If not, is it possible with the full edition of InstallShield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to custom actions->add new action that launches an executable. For working directory you may enter "SystemFolder", for Filename & command Line enter:

```
rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultInstall 128 .\<file>.inf
```

Return processing - Synchronous(Ignores exit code)

Then include this action somewhere into the install sequence. This should do the trick I believe. I am writing this post using a different version of install shield, but I believe it should still hold true.

EDIT: the line on how to install an info file is taken from [here](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/installation2/how-can-i-install-a-inf-file-from-the-command-line-)

**later edit by DaveDev:**

This worked. Just to clarify what needs to be done, I've included screenshots (because each pic saves me 1000 words, right?)

First, inf file needs to be included in "SystemFolder" section under the Files section of the installer configuration:

[image]

Second, in the Custom Actions section, the fields need to be filled in as follows. This is effectively everything that @izomorphius said, but this is a little bit more clear for those who aren't familiar with the product:

[image]

When this is done, build and deploy and the setup.exe should handle the installation of the inf file.

Comment: Hi @izomorphius, thanks for this but I don't think it'll work for me. I don't seem to have the option to "add new action that launches an executable" in my version. For reference, this is a screenshot of what I see: http://i.imgur.com/pCRmG.png - the lock symbols mean that I don't have that functionality available in the LE version.

Comment: And the "New exe option" is disabled? What is the type of Uninstall Existing?

Comment: Sorry, after poking around a bit I can see that it's disabled where there's a lock symbol, but not where there *isn't* a lock symbol. I can add a new exe as a "new custom action" from there it seems I can add the options you are referring to, e.g. http://i.imgur.com/nbEYu.png.. Also, I'm not sure about the uninstall - I still have to figure out if that's possible.

Comment: Well, uninstall will happen in a similar manner but you need to know how to use rundll32 to uninstall an inf. Can not help there, sorry - maybe browse the web.

Comment: This did he trick, thanks. I've updated your answer to outline what I did to make it work for me.